# Is it possible to add items to the Start 'flyout' menu from code?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Is it possible to add new items to the Start 'flyout' menu?  By flyout menu, I mean the one shown in the image below. I've written a system tray Winforms application which allows me to swap between and set boot partitions without using BCDEdit and thought it may be nice to add this feature into the actual start menu.

Despite a lot of Googling, I didn't find a solution but I did see ways to switch existing options on and off through the registry.

[image]

Comment: Check out https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/74650-how-do-i-add-shortcuts-above-start-button.html

Comment: This one is pretty hardcoded by design. You only have access to the pane on the right where you can pin/unpin things.